# ASP.NET getting textbox value from inside a DetailsViews with a button is clicked; that textbox data is independent of the binded data

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

As written in the title, I am trying to get a textbox value from inside a DetailsView. However, the textbox value is not in the content of the Binded data in DetailsView, so when I try to get the text with the OnCommand method, I get an HttpContext error. Secondly, I can't reach the value using its ID, possibly due to it being in DetailsView. And finally, when I put the textbox and button outside of the DetailsView, I get the value, but the button and text shouldn't show up if there is no data to show in DetailsView.

This is my DetailsView code:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvÜrün" runat="server" GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-borderless" AutoGenerateRows="false" OnCommand="dvÜrün_ItemCommand">

    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("ÜrünID") %> TL                                    
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ÜrünAdı" HeaderText="Adı" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ÜrünKategori" HeaderText="Kategori" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ÜrünAçıklama" HeaderText="Açıklama" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ücret">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("ÜrünÜcret") %> TL                                    
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>                
            <ItemTemplate>
                Adet:
                <asp:textbox ID="Adet" runat="server" CssClass="text-center" textmode="SingleLine" type="number" min="1" max="20" Text="1"/>
                <asp:Button CssClass="pull-right btn btn-success" Text="Sepete Ekle" runat="server" OnClick="sepeteEkle_Click"/> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

After posting this, I found the answer immediately. This is my cs code:

```
public void dvÜrün_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ürünEkle")
        {
            string adet = ((TextBox)dvÜrün.FindControl("Adet")).Text;

        }
    }
```

This is the DetailsView code:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvÜrün" runat="server" GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-borderless" AutoGenerateRows="false" OnItemCommand="dvÜrün_ItemCommand">

    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("ÜrünID") %> TL                                    
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ÜrünAdı" HeaderText="Adı" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ÜrünKategori" HeaderText="Kategori" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ÜrünAçıklama" HeaderText="Açıklama" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ücret">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("ÜrünÜcret") %> TL                                    
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>                
            <ItemTemplate>
                Adet:
                <asp:textbox id="Adet" runat="server" CssClass="text-center" textmode="SingleLine" type="number" min="1" max="20" Text="1"/>
                <asp:Button CssClass="pull-right btn btn-success" Text="Sepete Ekle" runat="server" CommandName="ürünEkle"/> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```